# How to keyframe a paths extrude

Tags: animation, extrude

I already know how to keyframe a path moving but I want to keyframe a path have a extrusion, like growing.

Comment: someone help 

Answer (score 1):

Animating an extrusion done in Edit mode is tricky i think, but you can move the Vertices in Edit Mode to make a Path object (or any Curve or Mesh object for that matter) and make it grow that way. You can record this movement as a Shape Key and in turn animate the Shape Key with Keyframes.

1. Select the Path object in the 3Dviewport.
2. Then in the Properties window click the Object Data Properties tab (the small green curve icon)
3. Under Shape keys click the little Plus icon twice to add 2 shape keys. The fist will be your basis, the path that hasn't grown yet.
4. With the second shape key in the list selected, "Key 1", go into Edit Mode.
5. Now change the Path by moving its vertices and effectively make it grow. when you're happy with the shape leave Edit Mode.
6. Changing the Value under the shape key list will allow you to turn the basic path into the grown path. This value can be key framed and animated. Hover the mouse over the Value field and press <kbd>i</kbd>. Change the position of the blue marker on the Timeline, then change the Value of the Key 1 and press <kbd>i</kbd> again.

Admittedly not precisely what you asked, but i hope it helps : )

[image]